# iPhone:Find Wifi and Bluetooth nearby devices programmatically?

Tags: iphone

I am trying to find nearby WiFi devices programmatically from my application.
I have the following two questions.
1. Is there any API's to do this? Is there any sample provided to go through?
2. Is it possible to implement it from 3.0 SDK or 4.0 SDK?

The same thing i want to find nearby Bluetooth devices as well and want to send file using this from one device to another?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Game Kit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html)

As far as I know you can do what you want with Bluetooth but not WiFi (unless the devices are on the same wireless network). For WiFi I recommend you build your own server app that the iPhone clients advertise their location to and get "nearby" device info. Much like how Bump works. This way you don't need your clients to be on the same network.

Comment: Yes, i want to send a file(could be database file) from one iPhone to another. My app should be able to detect nearby Wifi and also Bluetooth connected devices (iPhone) and should able to send file. Is it possible on 3.0 SDK or it is only from 4.0? Is there any sample programs available for this?

Comment: Have you visited the link above? It points you to - (BOOL)sendData:(NSData *)data toPeers:(NSArray *)peers withDataMode:(GKSendDataMode)mode error:(NSError **)error  Have a look at the documentation here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/GKSession/sendDataToAllPeers:withDataMode:error: